# Definition of the Number Two in ZF Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, natural-numbers

[This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers) shows how natural numbers may be defined as unions of sets.

What is a straightforward way to appeal to intuitive notions to dispel the misconception that
{Ø} + {Ø} = {{Ø}, {Ø}, Ø} and instead show that
{Ø} + {Ø} = {Ø, {Ø}} 
?

Comment: But $\{\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset\},\emptyset\}$ **is** $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ !

Comment: Furthermore, there's no particular reason why $0$ has to be defined as the empty set, $1$ has to be $\{\emptyset\}$, and so on. We could equally well define $0$ to $ \{\emptyset \}$, and $1$ to be $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\} \}$, etc. Of course, we'd then have to modify the definition of successor, and of addition, etc. --- but all we're looking for is a collection of distinct things that we can use to represent the natural numbers (in some orderly way to make other steps easier).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\{x,x,y\}=\{x,y\}$. So the two sets you suggest are in fact the same.